# How to install and use mysql connector/odbc on a linux instance on AWS server

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ejabberd

I have a application that connects through the database through ODBC connectivity to connect to the mysql database. I had a server called ejabberd installed on my system(Windows 10). I had the compiled files of my application placed inside the folders of this server ejabberd and made calls from the clients and it ran fine since the odbc configuration on my system was done alright by me.

But now I have a linux machine on AWS server. I have installed this server ejabberd on this linux instance, so all the folders of ejabberd are on some other linux machine. Now when I will paste the compiled files of my application on this linux machine inside the ejabberd folder they will again look out for ODBC configuration that should be present on that linux instance to connect to the mysql tables placed there.

So my question is that how can I download mysql connector/odbc on the linux instance and provide the DSN configuration since it is a linux machine and I only know the method of configuring DSN through GUI on my windows machine. If anyone have any Idea about this kindly share your Ideas. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Using ejabberd with MySQL](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/databases/mysql/) page describes how to configure the database connection. After loading the database schema you can set the connection properties:

> In ejabberd.yml, define your database parameters:
>
> sql_type: mysql
>
> sql_server: "localhost"
>
> sql_database: "ejabberd"
>
> sql_username: "ejabberd"
>
> sql_password: "password"
>
> sql_port: 3306

Comment: Yes I have been using ejabberd with mysql by editing these values only but actually my question is something else. I have a common_db.erl file in my application with a connection string defining the connection parameters like name of the dsn, username,database name etc. I did this on windows very easily using GUI MySql connector/odbc. But I have to do this on the AWS linux instance now and I am not familiar with linux. So if you may know that how to do so on a linux machine kindly do share.